# What's the name of the area between two geographic coordinates?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, geodesy, geodesic

Is there a name for the shape of the area defined by two sets of geographic coordinates, for example by a northwestern and southeastern corner? In other words, the shape bounded by two degrees of longitudes and two degrees of latitude? Since it's on a sphere/ellipsoid, it's not a rectangle or a trapezoid. Is there another good name for it then? A quadrangle? I've looked on wikipedia, google and stackexchange, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: spherical trapezoid...

Comment: may be bounding box?

Comment: Since you seem to be the first one to express the need to name it, let's call it a "Niaedu shape" :-)

Comment: I would say it depends on how you define the boundaries that span the limits, let alone how they wrap in longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More informally than a *spherioidal quadrangle*, a much more common and useful term is "bounding box", sometimes shortened to "bbox".

Answer (score 2):

> A quadrangle?

Yes, it is named: *spheroidal quadrangle*.